# "Approved" Button and "Rejected" button links

Tags: 2007, content-approval

Usually, one can approve or reject a item by clicking on the item in a particular Sharepoint 2007 list.

May I know how is the link generated for both the "Approved" and "Rejected" radio box?

[image]

From what I know, when I enter the following

`http://mysite.com/subsite/_layouts/approve.aspx?List={LIST_NAME}&ID={ID_OF_THE_ITEM}&Source={THE_ASPX_LINK_OF_THE_VIEW}`

it will take me to the approve/reject screen.

I suspect that the link to the approve radio box could be:

`http://mysite.com/subsite/_layouts/approve.aspx?List={LIST_NAME}&ID={ID_OF_THE_ITEM}&Source={THE_ASPX_LINK_OF_THE_VIEW}&Action=Approved`

but was not sure if I am right.

Appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Are you looking for links to the approved radio button?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for links to both "Approved" and "Rejected" radio button as shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure that if you are looking for the links to the 'Approved' and 'Rejected' radio button but I would suggest the following alternative if you know how to use SPServices:

Try creating a new column (a single text field column should be fine) and named the column "isitApproved".

Then create a page using SPServices that provide two button - "Yes" and "No".

Also, create a workflow that detect the "isitApproved" value. If the "isitApproved" value equal to "Yes", then update the "Approval Status" to "Approved". If the "isitApproved" value equal to "No", then update the "Approval Status" to "Rejected".